# Which should come first, novel, Comic Book or Screenplay?

Tags: creative-writing, technique

I have planned out my novel, but I also want to adapt it into a screenplay and comic book with a lot of differences. I have been pondering if it should be the other way around, or should I start with an alternative order?

Answer (score 2):

Start with the one you're most excited about. The one you would have the most fun creating.

Answer (score 2):

If you have "a lot" of differences among the three media, then you have three different stories coming from the same kernel of an idea. Write them in whatever order you like — for pleasure, for money, for ease of completion.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, you have an idea that you imagine taking all of three forms:

- literary
- live–action audio-visual
- graphic

Each of those requires a different investment of resources and different techniques to bring to completion.

I too like to imagine the formations my stories would take if produced on different media.  However, for each story I have one platform which I know would serve it best.

I work on whichever platform I am most ready to work.
Some of my planned projects are sitting on an interminable backburner:  they will wait there until I am ready to begin pursuing them properly.

Which one is should you choose?
My answer would differ from yours:  I know nothing about your finances, network of friends and the like, or your skills.

It sounds like writing a novel would require the least extra work on your part.
So, do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are serious about multi-channel distribution, you should start with the channel that has the most rigoros demands on content and structure, and that is film.

There are very few movies made, so competition among scripts is extreme. If you want to get your story to be made into a movie, you better write it that way. That doesn't mean that you actually have to write the script, but that you should work on the outline of your story *as if* you were going to write a script. Then write the novel from that outline, be successful with it, and have Hollywood buy the movie rights.

Comment: On the contrary, if you want to sell as script, write a treatment or a full script and sell it as such. If you want to write a book that might get made into a movie, write it to be the best book it can be. Movies and books are fundamentally different art forms, and the movie version of a book is a complete retelling, with a very different outline. But to get there, you first have to get published, and anything short of the best book you can write is unlikely to achieve that. Then someone in Hollywood has to fall in love with your book as a book. Again, it needs to be the best book it can be.